# How do I set values for variables in my .robot file through PHP?

Tags: php, robotframework

Basically,  I want to do some web testing through Robot Framework. However, I would like to have the user change the variables without needing to edit the .robot file.

Here is part of what I will be using:

```
`*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library`

`*** Variables ***
${HOMEPAGE}    http://"website-name"/
${BROWSER}     Chrome
${USERNAME}    *****
${PASSWORD}    *****
${DELAY}       10
${LOGIN}       link=LOGIN`
```

I would like for the user to be able to change certain variables such as ${USERNAME} or ${PASSWORD} through a front end landing page that I've set up. I will get these data in PHP via a form that they will enter.

The only problem is, I still have no idea how to inject these variables into my .robot file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the variables via the command line. So what I suspect you could do is create the command line command to fire off your test via the PHP input, and then just fire it off.

```
PHP input > Command containing variable edit > fires off test with desired variables
```

You can do this via the `--variable` option on the command line for firing off your tests. In your case it would look something like this:

```
robot --variable USERNAME:Username test.robot
```

how it would look like in PHP, is down to you... But the `--variable VARIABLE_NAME:value` would be the direction for you to take.

read more about it [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-variables-in-command-line).

You essentially want to capture the input from the user via PHP. Inject that input into the `--variable` option on the command line, and get PHP to fire off the python / robot for you. That's what I would do.

Any questions please ask.

Comment: Thanks. Will definitely look into it. See what I can manage to come up with